# Find where the line crosses the x and y axis given a coordinate and slope

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question:

> The tangent of the angle that a straight line makes with the x-axis is
>   2.  If the point (5, 4) lies on this line find where the line crosses the x-axis and y axis

The book has not really covered the equation of a line yet so I am trying to solve without using that.

I am assuming I need to use the ratio 2:1 on (5, 4) to find the point when the line crosses both axis.

I am rather clumsily able to get the answer by saying to myself that to find the point where the line crosses the y axis I can to take the value y coordinate 4 of (5, 4) and the number of steps I need to get back to 0 are:

${4 \div 2}$

Then I could work out that I need to take 2 steps back from the ration 2:1 which would give me:

${((5 - 2), 0)} = (3, 0)$

I did the same for the point that crosses the x axis.

I worked out when x would be 0 by subtracting the x coordinate of (5, 4) and dividing it by 1 from the ration 2:1

${5 \div 1}$

I could then work out that I needed to take 5 steps back on the y axis and using the ratio 2:1 is ${(0, 4 - (5.2)) = (0, -6)}$

Is there an algorithm or some way I could have made this an easier calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of a straight line is equal to the tangent of the angle it makes with the $x$-axis, and it is also the number $a$ in the equation $y=ax+b$, so in your case you just plug in the point $(5,4)$ in the equation $y=2x+b$ and you get $b$, hence the points of intersection with the axes.

Comment: why did you use y = ax + b instead of the slope form?  I'm not sure I can tell when to use one or the other.

Comment: It does not matter what form you use. FThey are all equivalent.